# Can an injected class name be used as a type name in a friend declaration?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, class-template, friend-class, injected-class-name

Consider this code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
};

class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {
    friend class Singleton;
};
```

It compiles in gcc and clang, but is it valid? [temp.local].1 says:

> When it is used with a template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template template-parameter, or as **the final identifier in the elaborated-type-specifier of a friend class template declaration**, it is a template-name that refers to the class template itself.

The bold part seems to apply, and a friend declaration seems to require a type name and not a template name (see [class.friend]).

Are the compilers wrong or am I misreading the standard?

Comment: I think it would need to be `friend class Singleton<Logger>;` to allow a *specific instantiation* of the template base class to be a friend, not all possible instantiations of the template.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Befriending *all* instantiations would  be `template <class L> friend class Singleton<L>;` - not what's in the OP.

Comment: **[temp.local]** (as a sub-section of **[temp.res]**) is primarily about names that are used inside *template* definitions. Indeed, if one modifies your example a bit [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/whWoaMqi2wwyAiRH) immediately reject the code. I'm uncertain if the section applies equally for the injected-class name when used in non-templates too.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica [your example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/whWoaMqi2wwyAiRH) falls on [\[temp.dep\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep#3). This would be the case for even [a more simple one](https://godbolt.org/z/EvYYGz).

Comment: The bold part does not apply because the name is not in a "friend class template declaration" (like `template <class> friend class Singleton;`), just a "friend class declaration".

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica _Befriending all instantiations would be `template <class L> friend class Singleton<L>;`_ [temp.friend]/7: Friend declarations shall not declare partial specializations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When it is used with a template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template template-parameter, or as **the final identifier in the elaborated-type-specifier of a friend class template declaration**, it is a template-name that refers to the class template itself.

The condition in bold does not apply to the example because the name appears within a friend class declaration, but not a friend class *template* declaration.

Similar code where the part in bold does apply:

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
};

class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {
    template <typename> friend class Singleton;
};
```

The friend class template declaration redeclares the class template `Singleton` and makes it a friend. The same syntax is also legal as a first declaration of a class template (see [the example in [temp.friend]/1.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.friend#1.4) where class template `frd` is declared and befriended), but a first declaration can't be an instance of an injected class name.

Answer (score 2):

All examples in [[temp.local]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local) that use inheritance are using a *templated Derived class*, thus there is a need to access the Base with a qualified name, i.e. *through the Derived*, as in [[temp.local]#example-2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#example-2):

```
template <class T> struct Base {
  Base* p;
};

template <class T> struct Derived: public Base<T> {
    typename Derived::Base* p;   // meaning Derived​::​Base<T>
};
```

This is in order to overcome [dependent name lookup rules](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep).

There isn't an example for *non-template Derived* in this section of the specifications, but if the Derived is not templated, the following should work as well:

```
// same Base as above
struct Derived: public Base<int> {
    Base* p;   // meaning Derived​::​Base<int>
};
```

This is interpreted as:

```
struct Derived: public Base<int> {
    Derived::Base* p;
};
```

Which is interpreted as:

```
struct Derived: public Base<int> {
    Derived::Base<int>* p;
};
```

In our case:

```
class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {
    friend class Singleton;
};
```

Is same as:

```
class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {
    friend class Logger::Singleton;
};
```

Which is same as:

```
class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {
    friend class Logger::Singleton<Logger>;
};
```

It is to be noted that the definition in the spec of [injected-class-name](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.pre#def:injected-class-name) refers to:

> The class-name is also bound in the scope of the class (template) itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.

I would take the fact that the word `template` appears in parenthesis, as a hint by the spec that *injected-class-name* may appear also in a non-templated class. And in fact it is used elsewhere in the spec, in a non-template context, for example [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.spec#example-4) and [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual-1.1).

To close this, the spec adds, at [[dcl.type.simple]#note-1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#note-1):

> An injected-class-name is never interpreted as a template-name in contexts where class template argument deduction would be performed ([temp.local]).

**So, I would say that your code is compliant with the specifications.**

---

Note that [[temp.local]#example-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#example-1) refers to cases where the compiler would not see `class Y` as `Y<int>` but rather as `::Y`:

```
template<template<class> class T> class A { };
template<class T> class Y;
template<> class Y<int> {
  Y* p;                                 // meaning Y<int>
  Y<char>* q;                           // meaning Y<char>
  A<Y>* a;                              // meaning A<​::​Y>
  class B {
    template<class> friend class Y;     // meaning ​::​Y
  };
};
```

The last example works in our case as well, for declaring all types of Singleton befriended:

```
class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {
    template<class> friend class Singleton; // refers to ::Singleton
};
```

Above however doesn't compile in GCC due to an [old reappearing bug in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52625).

To overcome the GCC bug, one can use the more verbose option:

```
class Logger : public Singleton<Logger> {
    template<class> friend class ::Singleton; // OK with GCC and Clang
};
```

Code to play with: https://godbolt.org/z/Mcez17

Comment: This answer doesn't address the quoted sentence in [temp.local].

Comment: It refers to a friend class _template_ declaration where your case is a friend class declaration.