# Is it valid C++ if in a member function declaration of a variadic template class I assign the class type as a default template template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

in a nutshell: this code compiles in clang++ (10.0) and doesn't in g++ (12.2). Which one is right?

```
template<typename... T>
struct V{
  template<template<typename...> class U=V, typename T2>
  static void foo(T2){}
};

int main(){ 
  V<int>::foo(0);
}
```

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments, the last version of GCC compiles this code. There is also a very simple workaround, which works with older GCC versions too, i.e. to create an alias template like this

```
template<typename... T>
struct V{

  template<typename ... TT> 
  using vars = V<TT...>;

  template<template<typename...> class U=vars, typename T2>
  static void foo(T2){}
};

int main(){ 
  V<int>::foo(0);
}
```

Notice that this is slightly different from other posts, like this one [How do I use the class-name inside the class itself as a template argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287778/how-do-i-use-the-class-name-inside-the-class-itself-as-a-template-argument)
which highlights an MSVC bug. Here we show a GCC bug (present until version 13.0) which only happens when we assign the class as default argument to a template template argument of a member function. The class name injection otherwise works normally, as demostrated by the workaround.

Comment: when asking about compiler errors, please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: Both gcc and clang [compile this](https://godbolt.org/z/1x6r8df3T). While doing tests always update the compilers to the latest version.

Comment: This seems to be a msvc bug. See the same error occurring in the dupe: [How do I use the class-name inside the class itself as a template argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287778/how-do-i-use-the-class-name-inside-the-class-itself-as-a-template-argument). Also same error on msvc in another dupe: [Can an injected class name be used as a type name in a friend declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888872/can-an-injected-class-name-be-used-as-a-type-name-in-a-friend-declaration)

Comment: It is actually a GCC bug for versions below 13.1. As the workaround above shows, the class name injection works if used in a template alias.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the error is (with gcc 12.2):

```
<source>:3:42: error: invalid use of type 'V<T>' as a default value for a template template-parameter
    3 |   template<template<typename...> class U=V, typename T2>
      |                                          ^
```

Relevant topic here is injected-class-name. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name):

> In a class template, the injected-class-name can be used either as a template name that refers to the current template, or as a class name that refers to the current instantiation.

This and the fact that later gcc versions accept the code hints at a compiler error in gcc that has been fixed in newer versions.

Comment: @user12002570 looks like the same bug in MSVC, which also complains about `V` refering to the class not to the template. I see no reason why `V` should not refer to the template in that code